# specific field value in mongocxx

Tags: c++, mongo-cxx-driver

I want to have all the values of a specific field in my mongodb using mongocxx. I have 100 documents in my collection and each having a field "X1_position", the values of this field is float. I want to get all the 100 values of that field and want to store it into an array.
I am using following code, but it is not working

```
  #include <iostream>

  #include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
  #include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>

  #include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
  #include <mongocxx/options/find.hpp>
  #include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
  #include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>

  using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;
  using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_document;
  using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document;
  using bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;

  int main(int, char **) {
  mongocxx::instance inst{};
  mongocxx::client conn{mongocxx::uri{}};

  auto coll = conn["my_data"]["exp1"];

  bsoncxx::builder::stream::document mydoc;
  mydoc << "X1_Position";
  mongocxx::cursor cursor = coll.find( mydoc.view() );
  for(auto &&doc : cursor) {
      std::cout << doc["X1_ActualPosition"].get_utf8().value << "\n";
   }

  }
```

It compiles fine but gives following error while running the executable file.

```
    ./testmongo
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'bsoncxx::v_noabi::exception'
    what():  can't convert builder to a valid view: unmatched key
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you're after is [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).
You don't need to filter since you said you want all docs, but you need to tell MongoDB which fields you want back:

```
auto coll = conn["my_data"]["exp1"];

bsoncxx::builder::stream::document mydoc;

// Use projection to pick the field you want
// _id must be explicitly removed since it is returned by default
bsoncxx::builder::stream::document myprojection;
myprojection << "X1_ActualPosition" << 1 << "_id" << 0;

mongocxx::options::find opts{};
opts.projection(myprojection.view());
    
mongocxx::cursor cursor = coll.find(mydoc.view(), opts);
    
for (auto &&doc : cursor) {
    std::cout << doc["X1_ActualPosition"].get_double() << std::endl;
}
```

The error you get is because you're trying to build the query passing a key without a value to filter the docs, I think it would be similar to execute the following in mongodb interpreter (which also crashes):

```
db.exp1.find({"X1_ActualPosition"}) // ERROR: SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. It helped me. I got the value of the field by this method   "std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << "\n"; " but there is also the title of the field included. how to remove it?

Comment: can you provide me any link for mongocxx code examples. how can i get this data into an array?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by array.
If you're happy with transforming it into a vector, one simple (not very efficient I guess) way would be to loop and push into a vector: 
"std::vector<double> v;
    for (auto doc : cursor) {
        v.push_back(doc["X1_ActualPosition"].get_double());
    }"

Comment: If what you mean is to retrieve it as a bsoncxx::array, you can use aggregation:
"mongocxx::pipeline p{};
    p.group(make_document(
        kvp("_id", NULL),
        kvp("AllPos", make_document(kvp("$addToSet", "$X1_ActualPosition")))
    ));

    auto cur = coll.aggregate(p, mongocxx::options::aggregate{});

    std::vector<double> vec;
    for (auto &&doc : cur) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
        auto arr = doc["AllPos"].get_array().value;
        for (auto e : arr) { std::cout << "e:  " << e.get_double(); }
    }"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your reply.
I got the following output by running this command

```
  "std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << "\n";

  output 

  { "X1_ActualPosition" : "1.41E+02" }
```

i only want to get the valye 141. how can i remove first title string and how to convert second string into integer or double? The following code giving me error

```
   std::cout << doc["X1_ActualPosition"].get_double() << std::endl;
```

error

```
  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'bsoncxx::v_noabi::exception'
   what():  expected element type k_double
  Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Execute it from the mongodb shell to see what are the contents of this field (don't trust the json for mongocxx). Maybe you need to sanitize the values so all hold valid float values and not strings. I believe this should be rather a different question than a reply to the current question :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will rephrase my question and will post it again